# How to extract data from RakuAST 's

Tags: raku

How best is it to extract a hash from the `config` portion of a `RakuAST::Doc::Block` ? Here is the program:

```
use v6.d;
use experimental :rakuast;

my $ast = Q:to/CONF/.AST;
=for rakudoc :category("Language") :kind<sub> :subkind<operator>
Stuff
CONF
my $block = $ast.rakudoc[0];
my %config = $block.config.pairs.map( { .key  =>  .value.DEPARSE } );
say %config.raku
```

Here is the result.

```
{:category("(\"Language\")"), :kind("<sub>"), :subkind("<operator>")}
```

But `.DEPARSE` is producing the quotation markers, viz, `("...")` and `<...>`. How can I just extract the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>The `.DEPARSE` method attempts to re-create the original Raku code.  For strings this means quotes are included.</s>

If you want to get to the actual values, you can call the `.literalize` method on any RakuAST object.  This will either return `Nil` if it cannot be  literalized, or the actual value if it can.

UPDATE:
It was a while when I worked last on this.  While the above will work, there is actually already a method that will DWIM: [`.resolved-config`](https://docs.raku.org/type/RakuAST/Doc/Block#method_resolved-config).  So:

```
my %config := $block.resolved-config;
say %config;
```

will produce:

```
Map.new((category => Language, foo => (a => 42 b => 666), kind => sub, subkind => operator))
```

Note the use of `:=` instead of `=`.  While the `=` will also work, the `:=` will be much more efficient as it wouldn't need to copy anything.

Answer (score 1):

## `s/DEPARSE/EVAL/`

Change the first line below (copied from your code) to the line below it:

```
my %config = $block.config.pairs.map( { .key  => .value.DEPARSE} );
my %config = $block.config.pairs.map( { .key  => .value.EVAL} );
```

I had prepared a much longer answer. But for now it's just in a private gist I'm not yet ready to share. Hopefully one day I will have time to do so!

Comment: `EVAL` will  indeed also work, but it is a bit like using the swiss army chainsaw for its screwdriver.  In any case, this question has shown to me that either the `RakuAST::Doc::Block` class needs a "literalize" method, or the object returned by `RakuAST::Doc::Block.config` needs one.

Comment: UPDATE: there is a `.resolved-config` method that DWIM

Comment: Minutes after Richard published his Q I wrote the code `say .raku.EVAL for "(\"Language\")", "<sub>"; # Sledgehammer to crack escapes` and puns about nuts. "chainsaw" works too!  I decided there needed to be an answer discussing what to do instead, and set about drafting one. My gisted answer includes "Aiui, the duty of `.DEPARSE` is to reconstruct source code that would generate precisely the AST that it's "deparsing", so that, if parsed by a Raku parser, it would reproduce the AST that was `.DEPARSE`d.". Do you agree? It discusses "duty", "Raku parser", "source", rakudoc, and much more...

Comment: > "Aiui, the duty of .DEPARSE is to reconstruct source code that would generate precisely the AST that it's "deparsing", so that, if parsed by a Raku parser, it would reproduce the AST that was .DEPARSEd."   I agree